# How to make a image fit in 1/3rd of screen in flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to create a layout like this where the users will select and image and it'll take them to another screen like below and the selected image will take about one-third portion of the screen. The rest 2/3rd will be used as a canvas as you can see.

[image]

Unfortunately this is what I've got till now:

[image]

Here's the entire code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/src/components/Canvas.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/src/components/DrawingArea.dart';

class DetailsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  List<DrawingArea> points = [];
  final String imagePath;
  final String title;
  final int index;
  DetailsPage(
      {@required this.imagePath, @required this.title, @required this.index});

  // Display the selected image
  Widget displayImage(String imagePath) {
    return Container(
      child: Expanded(
        child: Hero(
          tag: 'logo$index',
          child: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, right: 50),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30),
                  bottomRight: Radius.circular(30)),
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage(imagePath),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("This will be the canvas"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            displayImage(imagePath),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set height of container which you can set by using MediaQuery as shown below:
Past this function in your code

```
Widget displayImage(String imagePath) {
return Container(
  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 3,
  child: Expanded(
    child: Hero(
      tag: 'logo$index',
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, right: 50),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30),
              bottomRight: Radius.circular(30)),
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage(imagePath),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

}

Comment: I see a MediaQuery.of(context).size.height /3
I understand it sets the height to one third but context seems undeclared in my code.
Undefined name 'context'.
how to solve this one?

Comment: You just need to pass context in that method as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I got you right. Is this what you're trying to get?

```dart
Column(
  children: [
    Expanded(
      flex: 1,
      child: Image.asset(
        'your_image_asset',
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
    ),
    Expanded(
      flex: 2,
      child: Placeholder(),
    ),
  ],
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Flexible: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flexible-class.html

https://youtu.be/CI7x0mAZiY0

```
Column(children: [
    Flexible(
        flex: 1
        child: Container(color: Colors.blue),
    Flexible(
        flex: 2
        child: Container(color: Colors.green),
    ),
   ]);
```